# MVC2 - Ghost Model Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-2

My Model:

```
public class EntryModel
{             
        [Required]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        public string Car { get; set; }

        public string Engine { get; set; }

        public string User { get; set; }

        public int CarCod { get; set; }
        public int EngineCod { get; set; }

    }
```

My View:

```
<%=Html.Label("Car")%>
<%=Html.Text("Car", car,new { @class = js_car")%>
<%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Car) %>
<%=Html.TextBox("CarCod", carCod, new { @class = "js_car", @style = "display:none;",@id="_car_cod" })%>
```

My Problem:

When posting the data, "CarCod" always fires an error at the ModelState, thus rendering both ModelState.IsValid and Html.ValidationSummary useless.

I already have workarounds for this (i.e not using them), but it would be very nice to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go off of what Garret said, make `CarCod` and `EngineCod` nullable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're hiding the `CarCod` textbox so it will be submitted with an empty string.  The Model expects it to be an `int` so it's having problems converting that to an integer.  What happens if you set the value to "0"?

Comment: I think we both actually solved the problem, but alas only one can be marked as the answer.  Daniel's answer is ultimately the right thing to do and what I'd recommend as well.